# Cannot change product name and attributes in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I have created a simple plugin that imports products from my CSV file, which works fine. The function for creating new products looks like this (simplified):

```
function create_products() {

    foreach($keys as $key) {

        // Assign variables
        // ...

        // Create new product
        $objProduct = new WC_Product();

        $objProduct->set_name($title);
        $objProduct->set_status("publish");
        $objProduct->set_catalog_visibility('visible');
        $objProduct->set_price($price);
        $objProduct->set_regular_price($price);
        $objProduct->set_manage_stock(true);
        $objProduct->set_stock_quantity($stock);
        $objProduct->set_stock_status('instock');
        $objProduct->set_backorders('notify');
        $objProduct->set_reviews_allowed(true);
        $objProduct->set_sold_individually(false);
        $objProduct->set_sku($sku);

        // Save it
        $product_id = $objProduct->save();

    }
}
```

It works well. After that I have another function that just updates the title, price, SKU and stock quantity of products that already exist. It looks like this (again, simplified):

```
function update_products() {

    foreach($keys as $key) {

        // Get product ID and it's object
        // $id, $objProduct

        // Assign variables
        // $title, $stock, $price, $sku

        // Perform updates
        update_stock($id, $stock); // updates '_stock' and '_stock_status' meta, runs wp_update_product_stock() method
        update_post_meta($id, '_regular_price', (float)$price);
        $objProduct->set_sku($sku);
        $objProduct->set_name($title);
        $objProduct->save();
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work at all. Somehow, the SKU (updated with `set_sku()`) and stock updating works. It gets updated, but the rest (name and price) does not. As for the title, I have also tried `wp_update_post()` method, and tried to change the `'post_title'`, but no results either.

All of them are **simple products**. How can I update their titles, prices and stock values?

Comment: Could you please check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51940338/updating-product-stock-programmatically-in-woocommerce-3

Comment: @Dmitry I've seen that question. The anwer from it is basically my update_stock() function.

Comment: @Dmitry my bad, the Stock was working, I just didn't notice. However, the problem with Title and Price persist.

Answer (score 1):

Try code below. I checked it's work fine.

```
function update_products() {

    foreach($keys as $key) {

        // Get product ID and it's object
        // $id, $objProduct

        // Assign variables
        // $title, $stock, $price, $sku

        // Perform updates
        // Create new product
        $objProduct = wc_get_product($id);
        if ( $objProduct instanceof WC_Product) {
            $objProduct->set_name($title);
            $objProduct->set_regular_price($price);
            $objProduct->set_sku($sku);
            $objProduct->set_stock_quantity($stock);

            // Save it
            $objProduct->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope help you. Check if product exist.

Comment: Almost there! The price works now. However, the title is still not changing.