# Increase/adjust product stock quantity for custom order status in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, backend, hook-woocommerce, orders

I have a custom order status called 'cancel-by-admin' which is set when an order is cancelled by site admin for some reason.

Now we need to increase/adjust the produce stock count when the order is cancelled. WooCommerce has already  provided 'cancel' order status and when it is set the stock count get adjusted by existing code. We need to implement the same functionality for 'cancel-by-admin' status.

How to achieve that? I am using Woocommerce 6.3.1.

---

Someone suggested to use the function `wc_update_product_stock()`. Also this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51940564/696680

But I am note sure what would be the best approach. Note that a customer can order multiple products in a single order, hence when the admin cancel the order, all the associated product quantity need to be adjusted.

To add the custom order status I use the following code:

```php
add_action( 'init', 'register_custom_order_statuses', 20 );
function register_custom_order_statuses() {
register_post_status( 'wc-cancelled-by-us', array(
        'label'                     => _x( 'CancelledByAdmin', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'CancelledByAdmin <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'CancelledByAdmin <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'woocommerce' )
    ) );
}
```

And my code attempt, where I could use some advice on how to proceed:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'func_status_changed', 10, 4 );
function func_status_changed( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order ){
     if ( $new_status == 'cancelled-by-us' ) {
        // Stock update operation goes here
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a custom order status I rewritten your code because:

- The `init` hook has been replaced with `woocommerce_register_shop_order_post_statuses` to register custom order statuses.
- `wc_order_statuses` is added to show the order status in the dropdown @ single order
- `bulk_actions-edit-shop_order` is added to show order status in the dropdown @ bulk actions

```php
// Register order status
function filter_woocommerce_register_shop_order_post_statuses( $order_statuses ) {
    // Status must start with "wc-"
    $order_statuses['wc-cancelled-by-us'] = array(
        'label'                     => _x( 'Cancelled by admin', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
        'public'                    => false,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        /* translators: %s: number of orders */
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Cancelled by admin <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Cancelled by admin <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'woocommerce' ),   
    );
    
    return $order_statuses;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_register_shop_order_post_statuses', 'filter_woocommerce_register_shop_order_post_statuses', 10, 1 );

// Show order status in the dropdown @ single order
function filter_wc_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {  
    $new_order_statuses = array();

    // Add new order status after cancel
    foreach ( $order_statuses as $key => $status ) {

        $new_order_statuses[ $key ] = $status;

        if ( 'wc-cancelled' === $key ) {
            // Status must start with "wc-"
            $new_order_statuses['wc-cancelled-by-us'] = _x( 'Cancelled by admin', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' );
        }
    }

    return $new_order_statuses;
}
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'filter_wc_order_statuses', 10, 1 );

// Show order status in the dropdown @ bulk actions
function filter_bulk_actions_edit_shop_order( $bulk_actions ) {
    // Note: "mark_" must be there instead of "wc"
    $bulk_actions['mark_cancelled-by-us'] = __( 'Cancelled by admin', 'woocommerce' );
    return $bulk_actions;
}
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'filter_bulk_actions_edit_shop_order', 10, 1 );
```

---

To answer your question, it is best to look at which functionality is applied for the existing `'cancel'` order status and then reproduce it.

In *wc-stock-functions.php* we can see that the function `wc_maybe_increase_stock_levels()` is called for both the `'cancel'` status and the `'pending'` status

To reproduce it we can use the `woocommerce_order_status_' . $status_transition['to']` **composite hook** that can be used with any custom order status.

So you get:

```php
// Maybe increase stock levels
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_cancelled-by-us', 'wc_maybe_increase_stock_levels' );
```